# store deleted if combobox deleted

Tags: extjs, ext.net

i have a store defined as :

```
<ext:Store ID="StoreTypeBoitier" runat="server">
    <Model>
        <ext:Model runat="server">
            <Fields>
                <ext:ModelField Name="id" />
                <ext:ModelField Name="type" />
            </Fields>
        </ext:Model>
    </Model>
</ext:Store>
```

my combobox is binded to the store :

```
<ext:ComboBox runat="server"  StoreID="StoreTypeBoitier" DisplayField="type"  ValueField="id" ></ext:ComboBox>
```

when i remove the combobox using javascript  **panel.remove(combobox)**, also the store is deleted.

How to avoid that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please set AutoDestroy="false" for the Store.

Comment: Thank you , that work's . another way to do it is to pass the false argument for autodestroy to the remove method panel.remove(item,false) and that's also works .

Comment: Correct. Though, the ComboBox won't be destroyed. It will be just removed from the Panel, but the ComboBox instance will stay.